# jQuery works on JSFiddle but not locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote a simple program to see if jQuery was working locally, turns out it was not. In this program hovering over the red box changes the box with no color below it to green.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sBk3M/495/

Here is the code locally (it doesn't work).

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .hoverbox {
        background-color:red;
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
    }

    .showbox {
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.hoverbox').hover(function() {
        $('.showbox').css("background-color", "green");
    });

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="hoverbox">
    </div>

    <div class="showbox">
    </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: You need to use [dom ready handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) as your script is executed before the target element is added to the dom...

Comment: In jsfiddle the script is by default added in a `window.onload` handler... see the second dropdown in the left side panel(under `Frameworks & Extension`)

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thank you very much, totally forgot to add that.

Comment: see [not working](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sBk3M/496/) and [working](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sBk3M/497/)

Comment: I recommend to read the [**jQuery tutorial**](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/).

Comment: @FelixKling is there a canonical question for dom ready issues....

Comment: @ArunPJohny: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196 (I guess)

Answer (score 1):

Put this code

```
$(function(){
     $('.hoverbox').hover(function() {
            $('.showbox').css("background-color", "green");
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like below :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.hoverbox').hover(function() {
          $('.showbox').css("background-color", "green");
      });
});
```

Reference for using `$(document).ready()` is [jQuery Dom Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)